# -Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false not working and getting MQRC_UNSUPPORTED_CIPHER_SUITE

Tags: java, spring, ibm-mq

I am using SSLCIPHERSUITE(TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256) in our application (verified that it is used in the generated binding file) and same ciphersuite is also configured on the channel.

However, I am constantly getting the below error –

```
2020-03-19 12:52:46,145 [Camel (camelContext) thread #13 - JmsConsumer[queue]] [WARN] o.a.c.c.jms.DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer [] - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'ABC' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'null'.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2400' ('MQRC_UNSUPPORTED_CIPHER_SUITE').
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'ABC' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'null'.
```

When looked at ibm mq logs at the client end, the ciphersuite it is using is `SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256`

Troubleshooting tried:

1. Using `-Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false`. Looks like this is not working for some reason and hence it is using SSL*** instead of TLS***. Tried a different ciphersuite as well and noticed same behavior. Configured same option in `JMSAdmin` call which generates binding file but no use.
2. Tried using preferTLS option provided by IBM but not useful in this case
3. Tried specifying FIPS setting at client end to YES and NO but same issue
4. Verified Java policy and it is unlimited strength jurisdiction policy
5. Verified Java version supports TLS**** cipher suite that is configured
6. Upgraded versions of ibm mq jars to 8.0.0.10 which is wmq client version on linux, also tried 8.0.0.12, 9.0.4.0, 9.1.**
7. Upgraded jms.jar to 2.0
8. Got certificates verified from MQ team and they all look right and complete

Can someone please let me know if they have faced similar issue and how it was resolved?

App is also using spring-jms 3.1.0-RELEASE and camel-jms 2.10.0

Comment: Which JDK / JRE are you using?

Comment: OpenJDK jdk1.8_221

Comment: Which version of IBM MQ produced the `MQRC_UNSUPPORTED_CIPHER_SUITE` error?

Comment: Hi JoshMc, wmq Client version is v8.0.0.10

Comment: You said you upgraded to 8.0.0.10, what were you at before?  Has the error remained the same? Can you grep for `SHA256` from your bindings file and post the results in an edit to your question (not in the comments).

Comment: Can you also provide the full output of `java -version` in an edit to your question.

Comment: You stated `When looked at ibm mq logs at the client end, the ciphersuite it is using is SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256`, the client end would normally mean the MQ client, can you edit and add the logs or error where you see this?

Comment: Thanks JoshMc, I was setting useIBMCipherMappings flag only one place at a time and it wasn't working...

Comment: I would have suggested that,  but item 1 under troubleshooting tried stated you already did set it both places?

Comment: Yeah but separately not together, tried one and didn't work so tried another cutting it from one place to other...

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved this issue. Had to configure `-Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false` at two places. One in java opts of tomcat server startup and other in JMSAdmin used for generating binding file.